# Use of the verb 'think' with an indirect object and direct object

Tags: objects

Is it correct to use a construction with the verb 'think', having an indirect and direct object, like the following, which I heard, I believe, on Thomas the Tank Engine and Friends from my childhood.

'We think him vulgar'

That phrase has stayed with me my entire life!

Dictionaries haven't turned up anything, so I wonder if this is dialectical or just plain queer.

Comment: The "think somebody/something + adj" construction is listed by the entry  for "think" in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, which is freely available online: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/think_1?q=think

Comment: I did not think to look on that dictionary; I must have looked up the noun instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your view of the verb construction is not correct. "vulgar" is an adjective, so it can't be an object.

The sense of the sentence is: He is vulgar, so I think. This was formulated with an ati-construction (accusative + to-infinitive):

- 1 I think him to be vulgar. - Compare: I hold him to be a good man/I imagine him to be a good man.

And "to be" was dropped:

- 2 I think him vulgar.

In 1 vulgar is a predicative complement after the copula verb/linking verb to be. In 2 vulgar is an object complement modifying him.

That's the way I would see the sentence construction.

OALD has a verb pattern/construction of the type: to think sb/sth + adjective - I think it highly unlikely that I'll get the job. - She thought him kind and generous.
See OALD think in no. 1  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/think_1?q=think

Of course, you can say it simpler: I think he is vulgar.

Comment: Oh whoops; yes, my mistake, vulgar is definitely an adjective. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**"We think him vulgar".**

Yes, it is, but there's only a direct object, no indirect object.

*Him* is direct object and *vulgar* is predicative complement. Note that the complement is said to be 'object orientated' because it relates to the object, rather than the subject. Its function is complement of the verb *think*, not modifier of *him*.