# What's the difference between "think it helpful" and "think it's helpful"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, to-be-deletion

Is the following a valid sentence?

> I think it helpful to mention the caveats in the document.

If so, how is the meaning different from this:

> I think it's helpful to mention the caveats in the document.

Comment: I am not sure the phrase "I think it helpful" is actually grammatical correct, not in the uk anyway

Comment: This is somewhat addressed by [Omitting "is", like in "I think it strange"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/40795/191178)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of the verb 'think' with an indirect object and direct object {sic}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316013/use-of-the-verb-think-with-an-indirect-object-and-direct-object) This deals with the first type of sentence, which needs explanation. But 'I think [that] it's helpful to mention the caveats in the document' or in general 'I think/believe/said/commented ... [that] {independent clause}' is a well known format.

Comment: Try it with other verbs and you'll see more patterns: _consider, believe, am convinced, am sure, determine, assess, doubt, ..._

Comment: @Laurel, why do you think that this is only 'somewhat addressed by' the other question, rather than this being a clear duplicate of it?

Comment: @jsw29 You're about a year too late  to ask that! It's possibly because this question is also asking about the difference in meaning, or possibly because that other question involves "that" clauses but not this one.

Comment: @Laurel, yes, I was well aware of the date of your earlier comment, but I have always assumed that Stack Exchange is supposed to be a permanent, continuously improving, repository of expertise and that it is, therefore, never too late to respond to something that stays posted on it (unlike on some discussion boards, on which engaging old posts is frowned upon). In any event, my main motivation for asking was to check whether you had in mind something that would constitute a good reason against voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it *helpful* to mention the caveats in the document.

This is the same construction as “I shot him dead” or “She arrived drunk”.

**Helpful** is a depictive. **Helpful** is a free modifier that modifies the main clause.

> I think *[that] it's helpful to mention the caveats in the document*.

**[that] it's helpful to mention the caveats in the document** is a content clause (A type of noun clause that describes the contents of the verb – here, what the thought was.)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion both statements have almost same meaning.
"think it helpful" or "think someone/something helpful" means to find something/someone helpful for some purpose or for some any work/task.

And "think it's helpful" is simply a statement that says that something or someone is helpful for someone or something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).